# Visual Studio connect to GIT server

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

we get the following error trying to connect to a git server inside our company network. proxy configuration to config file was added and works. same errors appears when i try to establish a connection to github.com

error:
libgit2. Category = Net (Error). Response status code does not indicate success: 417 (Expectation Failed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found the solution on my own. 
Editing the “devenv.exe.config” file and adding "expect100Continue" parameter solves the problem.

```
<settings>
<ipv6 enabled="true"/>
<servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>          
</settings>
```

connecting to github and our local gitserver work fine now.